# New Tab with ⌘-click in Sierra with sticky keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, accessibility

Prior to MacOS 10.12 Sierra, with Sticky Keys enabled, I could type ⌘, have it be "stuck", then click a link in a chrome browser tab and the link would open in a new tab. Now in Sierra, the same behavior opens the link in the same tab, even though the sticky key icon is visible. The only way to get ⌘-click to open in a new tab is to actually hold the key down while clicking (which defeats the purpose of sticky keys).

Is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way how to restore the old behavior however there appears to be a new (probably inconsistent) system:

For example, if you press <kbd>command</kbd> it is used only for one click (somehow not in browsers). A second press on <kbd>command</kbd> locks it and now it works in browsers too. The third press on <kbd>command</kbd> unlocks it and you are in the same situation as before.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I'm hoping to find a way that restores the old 1-press behavior, but if nothing is posted for a while I'll accept this as the best available option.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. When you are using sticky keys, double-press <kbd>command</kbd>. The indication will turn fully white. Now if you click on a link after double-pressing <kbd>command</kbd>, It will open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

As of macOS 10.12.5 (perhaps earlier, only noticed it now), the old behavior seems to be back. Tab the modifier key once then click the trackpad and the modifier is applied then released.